# Linq to SQL query error

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    public List<decmal> GetEnterCounts(DateTime StartTime, DateTime EndTime)
    {
        var db = new FACT_ENTER_EXIT();
        return (from e in **db.ENTER_CNT** where StartTime < db.DATE_ID && db.DATE_ID > EndTime select e).ToList();
    }
}
```

Ok, so I have this database FACT_ENTER_EXIT containing the field ENTER_CNT (nullable = false, type = decimal) which I want to return as a list

VS2010 spits out the following error at 'db.ENTER_CNT':

*Error  1   Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'decimal'.  'Where' not found.*

I must be missing something, could someone please point out where I'm going wrong??

Thanks in advance, Tom

Comment: You're defining a field on database-level? And then you're trying so select multiple values from that field? Something seems amiss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to select from the *table*, not from a *column*, then select from your column.

Try:

```
from e in db.MyTable
where StartTime < e.DATE_ID && e.DATE_ID > EndTime
select e.ENTER_CNT
```

This resembles the following SQL:

```
SELECT e.ENTER_CNT
FROM MyTable e
WHERE @StartTime < e.DATE_ID AND e.DATE_ID > @EndTime
```

Comment: Sorry, when I said database FACT_ENTER_EXIT, I meant table..

the FACT_ENTER_EXIT table comes from a data warehouse

I am not trying to create any tables!